# Can't access EC2 instance via public IP from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 instance. In this instance I have a security group. Even though it's not recommended to use, I set inbound rule to all traffic open everywhere.

In server I have a running apache tomcat and reaching it via localhost:8080.

Server gave me a public IP. When I type in my local browser "public ip:8080" gives me timed out.

I am not working on networking but basically I think settings is true. Ping gets time out also. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe your tomcat server is listening on localhost only? You should make it listen on 0.0.0.0 (all host ip addresses). Did you try to reach tomcat with the public ip (not localhost) from within the Amazon instance?

Comment: I added line address="0.0.0.0" in server.xml but nothing changed. In EC2 instance i can reach "private ip:8080". For public ip says this site can not be reached.

Comment: For people who faced same situation, i changed firewall inbound rule in EC2 instance. I opened every ports just to access from my local. You open 8080 port only.

Comment: open 8080 is enough and you can also stick to your ip only. If you are in a private subnet, you might need a NAT gateway on the public subnet.

Comment: Check few things : 
1. If the machine is inside a VPC, check that the subnet is not set to private.
2. Check inbound port is open .
3. try to connect via ssh -  `ssh -i <ssh-key> ec2-user@<instance-public-ip>`